# Issue with deleting data from Firebase Database due to validation rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is what I have:

```
 "products": {
        "$pid": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": "auth != null && (newData.child('quantity').val() > 0)",
            ".indexOn": ["subgroup", "group", "visibility"]
        },
        ".read": true
```

Now, If I try to delete, I am hitting exception.

> firebase.js:281 FIREBASE WARNING: set at /products/-KRdvStz-6EQ6OUJJcld failed: permission_denied

I really need the validation rule for having quantity >= 0. But I also need to be able to delete.

Any idea what needs to be done here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate data structure you should use a `.validate` rule:

```
"products": {
    "$pid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null",
        ".validate": "newData.child('quantity').val() > 0",
        ".indexOn": ["subgroup", "group", "visibility"]
    },
    ".read": true
```

Validation rules don't get triggered on data deletion, specifically to allow them to be used for this easily.

If you insist on using a write rule to validate, you can also do:

```
".write": "auth != null && (!newData.exists() || newData.child('quantity').val() > 0)",
```